# Running bash script that uses ssh and scp (prompts for password) securely

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, automation, scp

I am manually carrying out a series of files which involves generating files on my local machine and then copying them over to a remote machine.

Currently, I use scp and ssh to perform these tasks. At the moment, eash time I want to ssh into the remote machine, or do a scp, I am (quite rightly), prompted for a password. However, I want to automate the tasks into one script that I can setup to run with cron.

I have seen insecure solutions to this problem, which involve setting the PASSWORD in an environment variable. I am not comfortable with that. Can someone suggest another, more secure way of automating a script that uses ssh and scp?.

BTW, both my local machine and remote machine are running Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Set up authentication key so ssh will not prompt you for a password. e.g. [O'Reilly book](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/66) or [Debian](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password) You store your public key on the servers and then the private key on the clients

Answer (score 1):

Use public key authentication. There's an Ubuntu-specific tutorial here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys